# Where is GetModuleFileName?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to use GetModuleFileName() in Visual Studio 2013 but it says the symbol is undefined.  I've searched all .h files on my hard drive and "GetModuleFileName" isn't in any of them.

Has this function been replaced by something else?  In what file is it supposed to be defined?

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` should be all you need.

Comment: I agree, it should be that simple.  But it's not (at least for me).

Comment: WTH with the down votes?

Comment: Clearly it's a problem at your end due to code or settings that only you can see

Comment: Is this c/c++ or some `.Net` thing? Show your .cpp file, the one that includes `WinMain`

Answer (score 1):

Culprit found: Poco C++ #undefs a LOT of Windows functions.  Unnecessarily, IMHO, but it's something you can work around once you know it's happening.  See Poco's 'Unwindows.h' file for the list of Windows functions they un-define.

Comment: So you hadn't actually looked in winbase.h after all?

Comment: I did.  It is not in Winbase.h.  As I said, it's in "libloaderapi.h".  Microsoft's online documentation is out of date.

Comment: For future reference add the `poco` tag

Comment: It's most definitely in winbase.h.

Comment: Not in the 8.1 Win32 SDK, which VS 2013 uses by default (at least for me).  It's in "c:\program files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Include\um\WinBase.h" and "libloaderapi.h" in the same directory.

Comment: The real wtf is why POCO is undefining the Unicode versions and relying on the ANSI ones, but I won't bother investigating further; glad to know something like this was the issue.

Comment: The header files are where ever compiler says it should be. For example in VS-2015 it is here: `"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include"` POCO uses a different include directory, and is not standard c/c++ so they are not even the same files.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked. Nothing in the question mentions Poco. It's rather ridiculous to add an answer referring to Poco without having mentioned it in the question. What you must take away from this question is how important it is to describe your environment sufficiently that other may reproduce your problem. This question has been a total mess.

Comment: This question and answer helped me a lot. I happen to also be using Poco. It is strange that Poco undefines this, and there is no reason that the OP would have thought that Poco was related to the problem (if he thought that he would have figured it out before posting). Everybody is sanctimoniously chastising the OP and saying, in effect, that he can't be experiencing what he's experiencing, or that he should have magically known what was related to the problem when posting. Give the guy a freakin' break. He had a mysterious problem, like we all have, all day long.

Comment: Note that if you run into this problem it is not necessary to rebuild POCO with `POCO_NO_UNWINDOWS`, as `UnWindows.h` suggests. You can just change your invocation of the given function to either the A or W version. In my case I changed `GetModuleFileName( ... )` to `GetModuleFileNameW( ... )`.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx):

[image: requirements]

Note the **Header** and **Library** portions, and the fact that the function is declared with `A` and `W` variants.

Comment: I read the documentation.  If it was that simple, I wouldn't be posting the question.  When I grep through all .h files for "GetModuleFileName", it should also find these two variants.  It does not.

Comment: On another PC I see "#define GetModuleFileName  GetModuleFileNameA" in a file called "libloaderapi.h".  There is no declaration in "Winbase.h"

Comment: @Bungles Something's happened to your include files then. Time to reinstall VS.

Comment: Tried to compile on the other PC and even for that one it doesn't like "GetModuleFileName".  I have to use "GetModuleFileNameA" explicitly, which doesn't make sense given the #define I mentioned above is in the same file.

Comment: There is no `GetModuleFileNameW()` and no `#else` around the `#define` in the same place? And you do have `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` defined in your project, right? If so, something is incredibly broken on both PCs... (You should also notice `winbase.h` includes `libloaderapi.h`; it's not an important detail because you're not supposed to include those directly anyway.)

Answer (score -2):

you maybe messed with project properties and accidentally removed the `kernel32.lib` from linker dependencies.

check if the configuration of the project has `kernel32.lib` in linker's dependencies

Comment: The error in question is a *compiler* error, not a *linker* error.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, AFAIK 'symbol is undefined'  is linker message. not compiler!!

Comment: @VladFeinstein, yes it should be unresolved indeed, but i am trying to keep what was posted in the question "symbol is undefined", what it matter here is the keyword `symbol` that mean linked message, this is not the compiler message.

Comment: The term *symbol* does not imply a linker error. If a compiler lookup fails, it will also report a *symbol* error.